# 累積比率（線グラフ）を棒グラフに重ねる方法がわかりません

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

線グラフと棒グラフを個別に表示する方法はできました。
これらを同じグラフに描画する方法がわかりません。

環境:
Anaconda-Navigator
Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0

線グラフ:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'value': [10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 100]
    }
)
    
df['accumulative_ratio'] = df['value'].cumsum() / df['value'].sum()

df['accumulative_ratio'].plot.line(color='darkblue')
```

棒グラフ:

```
df['value'].plot.bar(color='darkblue')
```

[maplotlibの棒グラフに累積比率を追加する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/messefor/items/aa2fc73e3046cc63de72)
をみようみまねで試しているのですが、下記でエラーです。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'value': [10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 100]
    }
)    

df['accumulative_ratio'] = df['value'].cumsum() / df['value'].sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bar = ax.bar(left=x_idx,
             height=df['value'],
             align='center',
             tick_label=df['name'],
             alpha=0.7
             )
```

エラー：

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-face40da5000> in <module>
     16 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     17 
---> 18 bar = ax.bar(left=x_idx,
     19              height=df['value'],
     20              align='center',

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1446         if data is None:
-> 1447             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448 
   1449         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

正直、 `plt.subplots()` から何か2つ（`fig`と`ax`）をもらっているようですが、いまいち使い方がピンと来ていません。

また参考資料リンク先に

> 第2軸に累積の折れ線グラフを追加
> ax2 = ax.twinx()

とありますが、重ねない場合は、`df['accumulative_ratio'].plot.line(color='darkblue')`というように、`line`を使えばいけたので`twinx()`を別途呼び出すなどの、お作法が必要な理由等がよくわかっていません。

どのようにすれば、グラフを重ねて表示できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データフレームの内容を見ますと、`df.value` の範囲は `[100, 10000]` で `df.accumulative_ratio` は
`[0, 1.0]` となっています。つまりスケールが大幅に異なっている、という事です。実際には `df.accumulative_ratio` もプロットされているのですが、`X` 軸とほぼ重なっています。

```py
>>> df
  name  value  accumulative_ratio
0    A  10000            0.602410
1    B   5000            0.903614
2    C   1000            0.963855
3    D    500            0.993976
4    E    100            1.000000
```

というわけで `df.accumulative_ratio` のプロットに `secondary_y=True` を指定します。

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  'value': [10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 100]
})

# set graph style
sns.set_style(sns.axes_style(style='darkgrid'))
sns.set_palette('muted')
sns.set_color_codes('dark')

# set accumulative ratio
df['accumulative_ratio'] = df['value'].cumsum() / df['value'].sum()

# plotting
ax_val = df['value'].plot.bar(
  width=0.8, color='#789ad9', alpha=0.7, label='value')
ax_acc = df['accumulative_ratio'].plot.line(
  ls='--', marker='o', color='red', secondary_y=True, label='acc. ratio')

# annotation
for i, v in enumerate(df.value):
  ax_val.text(i, v, v, ha='center', color='darkblue')
for i, v in enumerate(df.accumulative_ratio):
  ax_acc.text(i, v*1.01, f'{v:.2f}', ha='center', color='red')

# value axes attributes
ax_val.set_xlabel('Group')
ax_val.set_ylabel('Value')
ax_val.set_xticklabels(df.name)
ax_val.grid(True)

# accumulative ratio axes attributes
ax_acc.set_ylabel('Accumulative ratio')
ax_acc.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax_acc.grid(False)

# title
plt.suptitle('Example of barplot with secondary axis', fontsize=18)

# legend
plt.legend(
  *[sum(l, []) for l in zip(
    ax_val.get_legend_handles_labels(),
    ax_acc.get_legend_handles_labels())],
  loc='center right', frameon=False
)

# show
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1):

##### 棒グラフのエラーについて

記事が古いか何かで, APIが古くなってる可能性があります

```py
bar = ax.bar(left=x_idx,
             height=df['value'],
             align='center',
             tick_label=df['name'],
             alpha=0.7
             )
```

… これを
この様に書き換えればよいかも

```py
bar = ax.bar(df['name'], df['value'], align='center', alpha=0.7)
```

---

##### グラフ重ね合わせについて

複数のグラフを同時の場合 [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) を用いて `ax` あるいは複数の ax (`axes`) を準備し, そこに描画することに

```py
# using the variable ax for single a Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# using the variable axs for multiple Axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

今回の場合は, ひとつだけ用意し, 毎回 `ax` に対し描画することになります