# 右側縦軸を0から表示するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

以前に [累積比率（線グラフを棒グラフに重ねる方法がわかりません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77465/%E7%B4%AF%E7%A9%8D%E6%AF%94%E7%8E%87-%E7%B7%9A%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95-%E3%82%92%E6%A3%92%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%81%AB%E9%87%8D%E3%81%AD%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93) の質問をしました。

こちら重ねることはできましたが、右側の縦軸が`0.6`あたりから始まります。
右側の縦軸を`0`から始めると、ひとつめのデータが多くの割合を占めていることがよりわかると思うのですが、どうすれば`0`から始められますか？

上記質問、[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/77467/9008)から本質問に必要そうな最低限のコードを下記に書きます。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  'value': [10000, 5000, 1000, 500, 100]
})

# set graph style
sns.set_style(sns.axes_style(style='darkgrid'))
sns.set_palette('muted')
sns.set_color_codes('dark')

# set accumulative ratio
df['accumulative_ratio'] = df['value'].cumsum() / df['value'].sum()

# plotting
ax_val = df['value'].plot.bar()
ax_acc = df['accumulative_ratio'].plot.line(
  ls='--', marker='o', color='red', secondary_y=True, label='acc. ratio')

# value axes attributes
ax_val.set_xlabel('Group')
ax_val.set_ylabel('Value')
ax_val.set_xticklabels(df.name)
ax_val.grid(True)

# accumulative ratio axes attributes
ax_acc.set_ylabel('Accumulative ratio')
ax_acc.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax_acc.grid(False)

# show
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の`Axes.set_ylim(bottom, top)`が使えるでしょう。
[6.3. 軸の最小値・最大値の設定 - matplotlibのめっちゃまとめ](https://qiita.com/nkay/items/d1eb91e33b9d6469ef51#63-%E8%BB%B8%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%80%E5%B0%8F%E5%80%A4%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%A7%E5%80%A4%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)

こんな風にすれば出来ます。

```
# accumulative ratio axes attributes
ax_acc.set_ylabel('Accumulative ratio')
ax_acc.set_ylim(0.0, 1.05)        #### ←これを追加する ####
ax_acc.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax_acc.grid(False)
```